# Getting type corresponding to strings like int,float etc

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Is there any way (function/structs/templates) etc. in c++ where in if we provide strings like int,float etc. as input and then it returns corresponding type. To elaborate a scenario suppose from DB I was able to retrieve that data type of column say ITEM_NAME have type varchar (as std::string) so now i want to declare a c++ variable item_name(std::string) whose type will be corresponding to this column ITEM_NAME(varchar). Below is something i tried (sample code) but this is not working :

```
template<string coltype>
struct DatabaseType
{
   typedef COL_TYPE std::string;
};

template<string coltype="int">
{
   typedef COL_TYPE int;
};

std::string getDBType()
{
return "int"; 
}
int main()
{
DataBaseType<std::string("int")>::COL_TYPE x;
//need to call another overloaded function that returns value corresponding to DB Column name in x
getDBValue("ITEM_NAME",x); //note this is already defined overloaded function that can take std::string,float and int in place of second argument
return 0;
};
```

Comment: I'd make a simple switch with dynamic allocation like `case "varchar" :  item_name = new string()` declare `item_name` as a `void*` should allow you to allocate any type of data (I didn't try this solution and i'm not sure to understand clearly your problem)

Comment: Templates are compile-time construct, while std::string is not. Are all "string" you intend to match on are going to be compile time? Why would you want to use a template here anyway?

Comment: @Maxime I cannot use pointers and edited the question that will explain reasoning for the same

Comment: Would you tolerate something like an `enum` for the column types, rather than a string?

Comment: Your question is not very clear but I feel that you need to have a look at `std::variant` at some other related metaprogramming constructs.

Comment: What makes you want to write `DataBaseType<std::string("int")>::COL_TYPE` instead of just `int`? Remember, you cannot specify types at run time, so `int` must be known at compile time. Why stuff your (known) type into a string, only to immediately get it back as a type? (If you manage to get it back at all).

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely nonsense, but in principle realizable:

```
template<size_t N>
struct DatabaseType
{
   typedef int COL_TYPE;
};

unsigned constexpr const_hash(char const *input) {
   return *input ?
      static_cast<unsigned int>(*input) + 33 * const_hash(input + 1) :
      5381;
}

template<>
struct DatabaseType<const_hash("int")>
{
   typedef int COL_TYPE;
};

template<>
struct DatabaseType<const_hash("float")>
{
   typedef float COL_TYPE;
};

template<>
struct DatabaseType<const_hash("string")>
{
   typedef std::string COL_TYPE;
};

void main()
{
   auto i = DatabaseType<const_hash("int")>::COL_TYPE(10);
   auto f = DatabaseType<const_hash("float")>::COL_TYPE(1.0);
   auto f = DatabaseType<const_hash("string")>::COL_TYPE("dasdas");
}
```

This does not make sense because it is much easier to use enum:

```
enum Types
{
   TYPE_INT,
   TYPE_FLOAT,
   TYPE_STRING
};

template<Types N>
struct DatabaseType
{
   typedef int COL_TYPE;
};

template<>
struct DatabaseType<TYPE_INT>
{
   typedef int COL_TYPE;
};

template<>
struct DatabaseType<TYPE_FLOAT>
{
   typedef float COL_TYPE;
};

template<>
struct DatabaseType<TYPE_STRING>
{
   typedef std::string COL_TYPE;
};



void main()
{
   auto i = DatabaseType<TYPE_INT>::COL_TYPE(10);
   auto f = DatabaseType<TYPE_FLOAT>::COL_TYPE(1.0f);
   auto f = DatabaseType<TYPE_STRING>::COL_TYPE("dasdas");
}
```